# Docker printing out empty string instead of a value set during build

Tags: docker, dockerfile

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.11-slim-bullseye

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

ARG my_build_arg

CMD echo $my_build_arg
```

I want to set an argument at the time of building the image. So, I run this command:

`docker build --build-arg my_build_arg='my_fantastic_value' -t 'my_image' .`

When I run `docker run my_image` into the console, I am expecting that docker will print out 'my_fantastic_value'. Instead, docker prints a newline with no text. What is wrong here?

Comment: `ARG`s are not available at container runtime, only at image buildtime. We can define an `ENV my_build_arg_as_env=${my_build_arg}` and then `CMD echo ${my_build_arg_as_env}` instead. I discussed this topic in [one of my blog posts (`turing85.github.io`)](https://turing85.github.io/articles/2023/04-09-container-arg-and-env/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ARG` instructions do not persist in the image. You can use an `ENV` instruction instead, which does persist in the image:

```
...
ARG my_build_arg
ENV my_build_env=$my_build_arg
CMD echo $my_build_env
```

See more here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#using-arg-variables